# Meteor - UserIsInRole always returning false

Tags: meteor, roles, atmosphere.js

I Have added allaning:roles in my meteor-react project but 
**Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ["ADMIN"])** always returning false.
I have roles in my mongo as follows,

```
{ "_id" : "9B3D757wQA9Mz4RGt", "name" : "BUYER" }
{ "_id" : "PDCJH8D6JDo9fttFj", "name" : "ADMINKAMB" }
{ "_id" : "XFGsrfB3Xsm6F8LbQ", "name" : "SELLER" }
{ "_id" : "hDLSvdo6wMnF47BBz", "name" : "ADMIN" }
{ "_id" : "ADMINKAMB", "children" : [ ] }
```

Comment: Can you please add some more information? Which version of `alanning:roles` is listed under `.meteor/versions` and where do you add the admin role to the user, where do you access it?

Comment: A couple more things to ask: Did you add the "admin" role to the user? If you are running it on the client, did you subscribe to the roles?

Comment: Are the roles case sensitive? Usually the role is 'admin'

Comment: I have tried for all roles as mentioned in my edit all of them returning false

Comment: Hello @Jankapunkt , I am using alanning:roles@3.2.2  on my meteor 1.10.2, I have added roles at server side and trying to acces it from both client and server.

Comment: Maybe the subscriptions are not ready yet, what does `Roles.subscription.ready()` return?

Comment: Roles.subscription.ready() returning true @Jankapunkt

Comment: Can you please add the code where you do the checks?

Comment: I am checking in meteor methods and browser console @Jankapunkt

Comment: And where are these logs placed?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't placed any log @Jankapunkt

Comment: console.log is also a log

Comment: @Jankapunkt  I entered  Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ["ADMIN"])   statement in console of chrome and also on meteor shell

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the autopublish from yours packages, try to add this code

```
For my case, I create a file /imports/startup/server/publications/index.js

Meteor.publish(null, function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Meteor.roleAssignment.find({ 'user._id': this.userId });
    }
    return this.ready();
});
```

Then in server/main.js

```
import '/imports/startup/server/publications'
```